# How do i set Calender Bi-Weekly

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have my small code and I want to get the bi-weekly but can't seem to get it right. How do I Display bi-Weekly in the Calender class. On my Bi Weekly I just put in random code.

```
   case "Bi-Weekly": {
                beginCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
                break;
            }
case "Month": {
                beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                break;
            }


            case "Quarterly": {
                beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
                break;
            }
            case "Half Yearly": {
                beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
                break;
            }
            case "Year": {
                beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 12);
                break;
```

Comment: Consider not using the `Calendar` class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead you may add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project so you can use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,2);
```

is the right one even though I would do some testing on how it behaves around the year-change

Comment: The answer is correct (and if I said not to use the `Calendar` class, I would just be repeating myself).

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.DECEMBER, 25);

    switch (recurrence) {
        case "Bi-Weekly": {
            date = date.plusWeeks(2);
            break;
        }
        case "Month": {
            date = date.plusMonths(1);
            break;
        }
        case "Quarterly": {
            date = date.plusMonths(3);
            break;
        }
        case "Half Yearly": {
            date = date.plusMonths(6);
            break;
        }
        case "Year": {
            date = date.plusYears(1);
            break;
        }

        default:
            System.err.println("Unrecognized recurrence: " + recurrence);
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("Added for " + recurrence + " gave: " + date);
```

Trying the code out with the difference strings (in a different order) gave:

> ```
> Added for Bi-Weekly gave: 2020-01-08
> Added for Year gave: 2020-12-25
> Added for Quarterly gave: 2020-03-25
> Added for Half Yearly gave: 2020-06-25
> Added for Month gave: 2020-01-25
> ```

Have your calendar events got time of day too? No problem: the code works the same if using a `ZonedDateTime` or a `LocalDateTime` instead of a `LocalDate`.

The `Calendar` class that you used is poorly designed and long outdated. I find java.time, the modern Java date and time API, so much nicer to work with. Which is why I wanted to show you this option.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.